# Border Right is being set on the opposite of the page

Tags: html, css

When I place a border on the right of the text the border is always at the very right of  the page, not to the right of the text.
I've removed the default border properties of the browser and the result is still the same.

On the code pen the third result is what I want but with the border on the right.

Example: http://codepen.io/twig941/pen/zoqEXx

Code:

```
<div class = "logo">
The Three Words
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class = "ideal-logo">
  The 
  <br>
  Three
  <br>
  Words
</div>

<div class = "ideal-left">
    The 
  <br>
  Three
  <br>
  Words
</div>

.logo {
  border-right: 10px solid black;
}

.ideal-logo {
  border-right: 5px solid black;
}

.ideal-left {
  border-left: 5px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `display: inline-block;` on `.logo` & `.ideal-logo`. Currently they are `block` elements that is why they are flowing end-to-end.

Here is the snippet, have a look:

```css
.logo {
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 10px solid black;
}

.ideal-logo {
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 5px solid black;
}

.ideal-left {
  border-left: 5px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class = "logo">
The Three Words
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class = "ideal-logo">
  The 
  <br>
  Three
  <br>
  Words
</div>

<div class = "ideal-left">
    The 
  <br>
  Three
  <br>
  Words
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

A `<div>` is a `block`, which by default spans the entire width of the page.  Thus the right edge of each `<div>` *is* the right side of the screen, and the rest is empty space.

Using `display: inline-block;` will make the `<div>` shrink-wrap around its contents.  (This will also allow it to sit on the same line with text and other elements, so you might need an extra wrapper if you still want an overall block.)

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you are actually applying border on `<div>` and div is a block element you could try setting border to paragraph `

and it will work

**html**

```
<div class = "logo">
<p>The Three Words</p>
</div>
```

**css**

```
p
   {
    border:10px dashed #000;
   }
```

What you could also do is set a width to div and set a border around it but that is quite in-
efficient

Comment: `p` is a block level element just like `div`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `display: inline-block`.
The [pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KNzyNj)

```
.logo {
  border-right: 10px solid black;
  display: inline-block
}

.ideal-logo {
  border-right: 5px solid black;
  display: inline-block;

}

.ideal-left {
  border-left: 5px solid black;
}

<div class = "logo">
The Three Words
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class = "ideal-logo">
  The 
  <br>
  Three
  <br>
  Words
</div>

<div class = "ideal-left">
    The 
  <br>
  Three
  <br>
  Words
</div>
```